# References outside the current document

Tags: cross-referencing

I am a mathematics teacher (in France) and I would like to have all the proofs of the theorems in another document. To be more specific:

- a file named "Lesson" would contain the lesson itself
- anoter file called "Proof" would contain all the proofs of the theorems from the file "Lesson"

I would then have two separate pdfs. And I would like that the references of the theorems in the lesson file directly open the "Proof" pdf at the good position and vice versa (when I click on a theorem, it opens the proof and vice versa).

Is it even possible?

Of course I could use only one file and put all the proofs at the end of the lesson but I would prefer two separate files.

Comment: see the xr-hyper package, a hyperref extension to xr (which implements eXternal References.

Comment: Thank you, David. I will check that